# How can I override or customize the delete confirmation dialog in Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-xp

When we press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> key, a delete confirmation dialog is generated. I want to handle this dialog according my need or change its message. Can anyone tell me what thing is responsible for that dialog?

I either need to know the code which handles the delete confirmation dialog generated by the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> key sequence in Windows XP, or the code by which we can control this operation.

Comment: Could you explain why you want to control the dialog? Do you want to prevent any shift delete operations?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, other than mess with the delete confirmation dialog?

Comment: @giddy: I want to show my own dialog box.

Comment: *Why* do you find yourself needing to mess with the internals of the operating system? What's wrong with the dialog box as it is?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure I agree with the intent of the question, and certainly don't advocate it as a best practice, but hopefully my edits make the question clear enough that people will stop voting to close it as "not real".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think what you want to do is going to be fun.

**Im guessing** you have to **intercept** the [SHFileOperation function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762164%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) (and the [IFileOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775771%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) interface for Vista onward)

Here what my google-fu got me on winapi interception:
http://www.codeproject.com/kb/system/hooksys.aspx

You might want to look at this : http://easyhook.codeplex.com/

> This project supports extending
>   (hooking) unmanaged code (APIs) with
>   pure managed ones, from within a fully
>   managed environment like C# using
>   Windows 2000 SP4 and later...

Good Luck! =)

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to mess with the dialog (change the displayed text, image, etc.) you can try to modify the resources with a free tool such as [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/).

The "delete" dialog resources are in shell32.dll in Windows XP (you mentioned only that version of Windows); fire up the Resource Hacker and open shell32.dll, then search for the warning text "Are you sure you want to delete" and you'll find:

```
CONTROL "Are you sure you want to delete '%1'?", 12295, STATIC, SS_LEFT | SS_NOPREFIX | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_GROUP, 41, 10, 220, 28
```

Now that's only the static text, but the whole dialog definition (buttons etc.) should be here. I think this way you can make it a simple warning dialog--e.g. "You're forbidden to delete anything!" and only a "Cancel" button.

Comment: I just upvoted this, because it's technically a valid solution (and probably the simplest by far). But the thought still makes me uncomfortable...

Comment: Of course, I am by no means advocating quick and dirty tricks as part of a real project or production software. The context of the OP's intent missing, I just felt like mentioning an easy possibility.

Answer (score 0):

One way to address file deletion restrictions could be by employing NTFS security descriptors.

- [Security Descriptors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379563%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [Security Descriptor Operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379568%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

That way, you change it in one place and not have to worry about covering all cases to prevent deleting a file.