# Using FileSystemWatcher to monitor file creation and copy it before deleted

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

We have a 3rd party application that writes a file to a directory and then deletes it. 
We want to copy that file before it is deleted.

We have this:

```
    FileSystemWatcher watcher;

    private void WatchForFileDrop()
    {
        watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = "c:\\FileDrop";
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName;
        watcher.Filter = "*.txt";
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreated);
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    private void OnCreated(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        //Copy the file to the file drop location
        System.IO.File.Copy(e.FullPath, "C:\\FileDropCopy\\" + e.Name);
    }
```

The FileSystemWatcher does work.  It will see that the file has been created and it goes to the OnCreated().  The file is created in the directory.

The only problem is the file is empty and the file size is 0kb.

I wanted to double check my thinking of why the file is empty.  Is it because the file is deleted so quickly by the 3rd party application that it doesn't have the chance to do a proper copy?
thanks for taking a look.

Comment: If you are notified when the file is created, no closed, then the 3rd party application may not have written any data yet. You cannot use `FileSystemWatcher` to ensure that you have an opportunity to access the file after it is written and closed, but before it is deleted.

Comment: Proper temporary files are opened with no-sharing + delete-on-close, so you likely need much lower level code to intercept content because normal access checks will prevent regular user level code from accessing the file.

Comment: Filesystem filter driver is your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options 1:
Instead of looking at FileSystemWatcher, you should look to hook your code to delete event.
You can look this this comment on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4395147/442470

Option 2:
As soon as your FileSystemWatcher realizes that a file is created, change permission of the file so that it cannot be deleted.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  @Yogee - thanks ...I kept it simple and just changed the permission so the file is not deleted.